# Creating a system-wide hook that adds a menu item to the system menu of every Windows program?

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit Windows 10 VCL Application in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I am trying to implement a system-wide hook that adds a menu item to the system menu of every Windows program. For this purpose, I have created and built this DLL:

```
library SystemMenuHookDLL;

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Classes;

{$R *.res}

function AddMenuItem(WindowHandle: HWND): Boolean;
var
  MenuHandle: HMENU;
  MenuItemID: UINT;
  WindowStyles: DWORD;
begin
  Result := False;
  MenuHandle := GetSystemMenu(WindowHandle, False);
  if MenuHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    MenuItemID := 999;
    AppendMenu(MenuHandle, MF_STRING, MenuItemID, 'My Menu Item');
    SetMenuDefaultItem(MenuHandle, MenuItemID, MF_BYCOMMAND);
    WindowStyles := GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
    WindowStyles := WindowStyles or WS_SYSMENU;
    SetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WindowStyles);
    DrawMenuBar(WindowHandle);
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

function HookFunc(Code: Integer; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if Code = HCBT_CREATEWND then
  begin
    AddMenuItem(HWND(WParam));
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(0, Code, WParam, LParam);
end;

exports HookFunc;

begin
end.
```

This is the code for the Host Application for the DLL:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  CodeSiteLogging;

type
  THookProc = function(Code: Integer; WParam: WPARAM; LParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;

var
  DLLHandle: HMODULE;
  HookProc: THookProc;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UnhookWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT);
  FreeLibrary(DLLHandle);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('SystemMenuHookDLL.dll');
  CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: DLLHandle', DLLHandle);
  if DLLHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @HookProc := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'HookFunc');
    CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: @HookProc', @HookProc);
    if Assigned(HookProc) then
    begin
      CodeSite.Send('TForm1.FormCreate: Assigned');
      SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProc, DLLHandle, 0);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

I have put the DLL in the same directory of the host application exe file. Unfortunately, it does not work: After having started the host application, and then trying to start a 32-bit program, the program does not start! It seems that the hook is blocking the program.

Comment: How do you know `SetWindowsHookEx()` succeeded?

Comment: I tried your code (minus the aggressive parts: defaultness, window style, menu bar redrawing (why?)) on my system, and it actually seems to work: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sdsj.png

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I've tried to remove all the superfluous things, but there still seems to be an obstacle. Can you show me the exact code you've changed?

Comment: @AmigoJack `var ThisHHOOK := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProc, DLLHandle, 0);` It gets a reasonable value.

Comment: @user1580348: No CodeSite. Other than that and the already mentioned changes, no changes.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand This my DLL code now: https://app.screencast.com/lGNLxbZcek2Bf is it the same as yours? Did you change anything in the host app too?

Comment: You need separate DLLs to hook 32bit and 64bit processes. Which means your will also need separate 32bit and 64bit host apps to load the DLL hooks

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am still not able to replicate the successful result of Andreas with a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue: your host app has a small bug on shutdown. When releasing the hook, you need to pass `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` the `HHOOK` handle returned by `SetWindowsHookEx()`. Also, your code only adds a menu item to new windows, not to existing windows

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the hint. So now I set: `FHHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProc, DLLHandle, 0);` and then: `UnhookWindowsHookEx(FHHook);` And about existing windows: I know, but I don't know how to do that. maybe I should implement the host functionality into a SERVICE, so all newly created windows can be catched by it?

Comment: "*I don't know how to [handle existing windows]*" - You can use `EnumWindows()` to enumerate existing top-level windows. I would probably use a `WH_GETMESSAGE` or `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook, and then post a custom message to each window, so the message hook executes in the context of the window's owning thread, just like the `WH_CBT` hook does. "*maybe I should implement the host functionality into a SERVICE, so all newly created windows can be catched by it?*" - that won't work, since the service will be running in a different session/desktop than apps run in. Hooks can't cross desktop boundaries.

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, that's exactly my code.

Comment: @user1580348: I hope you don't include the CodeSite unit in your DLL?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, I have removed CodeSite from the DLL. But I suspect there are still some differences. So PLEASE show your whole code. (Even from the host app, as I made some changes there too and I don't remember the previous code).

Comment: https://privat.rejbrand.se/hooktest.zip

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you very much; it works perfectly here: https://www.screencast.com/t/n0nrNk30Lm9 Now I will have to implement it in a service so that all windows created after Logon can be "hooked." I will also create both 32/64-bit DLLs and hosts, as Remy suggested. If you create an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @user1580348: No point in me writing an answer, since I only copied the code in your Q!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand BTW, you forgot to UNHOOK, as Remy noted.

Comment: @user1580348: Of course I would do that in a real application. I merely did a very, very quick test (basically a 30 sec copy and paste) to see where the problem were (and was persuaded to share the dirty test! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand My apologies.

Comment: And what were the differences? What made your project to fail and (importing) Andreas' (seemingly identical) project to succeed?